# A different suffix from an array for each line on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

What I need is to show a different valuesuffix for each chart type value based on a unique array for each series.

I have considered the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667749/a-different-suffix-for-each-line-on-highstock-highcharts) and created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xp47xe45/).`a`

It will only work when the tooltip is displayed for one series at a time. If I set the series [tooltip to be shared](http://jsfiddle.net/a8pp300g/)`a`, it will not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `tooltip` shared with multiple series, you need to loop the points like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/a8pp300g/1/) in order for the `tooltip` to work.

Edited: Added [valuePrefix](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/a8pp300g/2/)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Any idea how to also show the symbol for each chart type in front of the valuesuffix?

Comment: @Rafaelcode Not sure what you mean. I added valuePrefix for each series and updated my answer. Try to play around with the API.

Comment: In the given example Rainfall has a blue rectangle in front of it, and Temperature has a blackish circle with a line. Would be nice to include these in the tooltip as well.

Comment: @Rafaelcode You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973920/how-to-display-highchart-series-line-marker-symbol-from-tooltip-formatter